# Will Allah still forgive me for this terrible promise?

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness

I'm 13 years old, and I'm a girl.
I made a promise and I really regret breaking it.

I promised Allah that I would never sin, and if I did, I told him to never forgive me or listen to me afterwards. I broke the promise, and I by Allah i regret breaking it. I'm focusing on becoming a good Muslim, I'm learning how to pray but the thought still haunts me.

Will Allah still forgive me, and listen to me even though I broke the promise, or am I doomed?

Please answer! I don't want to go to hell, i regret sinning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

> "O  my sons! Go and search ˹diligently˺ for Joseph and his brother.
> **And do not lose hope in the mercy of Allah, for no one loses hope in Allah’s mercy except those with no faith.**” (Translation by Dr
> Mustafa Khattab)
>
> Qur'an 12:87

> "God does not hold you accountable for your unintended oaths, but He
> holds you accountable for your binding oaths. **The atonement for it
> is by feeding ten needy people from the average of what you feed your
> families, or by clothing them, or by freeing a slave. Anyone who lacks
> the means shall fast for three days. That is the atonement for
> breaking your oaths when you have sworn them. So keep your oaths. Thus
> God makes clear His Revelations to you, that you may be grateful.**"
> (Translation by Talal Itani)
>
> Qur'an 58:89

You need to prioritize

> feeding ten needy people from the average of what you feed your
> families, or by clothing them, or by freeing a slave.

If you cannot do that, then

> Anyone who lacks the means shall fast for three days.

And Allah knows best.